# How to override post-new.php with custom template

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, templates, redirect, admin-menu

How can i override `post-new.php` with my `custom template`. When i `include` file or simply redirect i see my template but admin sidebar is missing. I know it is not simple.

Answer (score 0):

This does sound very challenging. `post-new.php` isn't *template* really. It's a full–featured endpoint, that is PHP script directly requested by browser and processed by PHP engine as entry point. There is no good point to intervene this early in the process.

The bulk of output is handled by `wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php` which is hardcoded in it as well and not meant for override.

Depending on what needs to be done I could think of two approaches:

1. Methodically unconfigure, override, and otherwise strip all the features from edit screen until it's reasonably blank slate.
2. Build completely separate admin page altogether and use it instead of native one for the case.

Comment: How would you go about option 2. Building a separate Admin page?